# listitemsymbol in moderncv renders as "•[regular]" when using fontawesome

Tags: symbols, moderncv, fontawesome

I'm using `fontawesome` package to have `\faExternalLink`, but an undesired consequence is that `\listitemsymbol` is rendered as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Here's the minimal code to reproduce it:

```latex
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}
  \faExternalLink\\
  \listitemsymbol
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`moderncv`'s `classic` style internally loads `fontawesome5` which is incompatible to `fontawesome` (which loads Font Awesome 4).

You can avoid this by using the external link symbol from `fontawesome5` by removing the `fontawesome` package and adding `*` after `\faExternalLink` (since the icon is called `externall-link-alt` in Font Awesome 5).

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}
  \faExternalLink*\\
  \listitemsymbol
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative which at least worked well for me is by explicitly adding the package **fontawesome5** and then letting the program compile itself again

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}  

\usepackage{fontawesome5} 

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```